# OutputCache.VaryByHeader is not generating a Vary header in the response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache, http-caching

I have this action method:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 2, 
                 Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any, 
                 VaryByHeader = "Accept-Charset")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And the generated response is:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=2
Content-Length:5164
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 28 Sep 2011 16:30:33 GMT
Expires:Wed, 28 Sep 2011 16:30:35 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 28 Sep 2011 16:30:33 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary:*
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Why is the `Vary` header showing an asterisk instead of `Accept-Charset` ?

`OutputCacheAttribute` does have effect on the response, actually, the `Expires` and `Cache-Control:max-age=n` headers depends on the `Duration` argument, and the `Cache-Control:public`/`private`/`no-cache` depends on the `Location` argument.

I have created a wrapper for `OutputCacheAttribute` to see what is going on:

```
public class CustomOutputCacheAttribute:OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);

        Dictionary<String, String> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var header in filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.AllKeys)
            headers.Add(header, filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers[header]);

        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

The headers are not shown in the break, so probably what `OutputCacheAttribute` does is configure `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache`.

I can see how `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders.UserCharSet` is **true**, and for example `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders.AcceptTypes` is **false**, but the `Vary` header always says *****.

I am wondering if the only possible values are the four ones listed as properties of `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders`, could it be?

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is use [`Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setomitvarystar.aspx)

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 2,
         Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any,
         VaryByHeader = "Accept-Charset")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
        return View("ShowHeaders");
    }
```

I am still trying to figure out what is wrong with Vary:* in this thread: [What is the meaning of the HTTP header Vary:*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599964/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-http-header-vary)

Answer (score 0):

<%@ OutputCache Duration="2000" VaryByParam="*" VaryByHeader="Accept-Language" %>

Comment: What is that supposed to do? It sends the `Vary:*` header as well.