# VARY Header in HTTP Request

Tags: http-headers, vary

What is the use of VARY header in HTTP request? I am unable to understand the use of VARY header for cross domain and cache control.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the HTTP header Vary:\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599964/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-http-header-vary)